# Highlight specific elements of an embedded ruby array and display it as one sentence

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I would like to display a list of items as a sentence with the just some of those items highlighted in a different color. `<span class="class-name"></span>`.

I've managed to display it as two separate sentences (arrays) although I could not find a solution to join them both and highlight only the desired ones.

#### Although the code below worked for sorting I can't manage to find a satisfactory solution to display it.

```rb
# items = ['flour', 'oil', 'egg', 'salt']
# in_stock = ['flour', 'oil']
# items_in_stock = []
# items_not_in_stock = []

items.each do |item|
 if in_stock.include?(item)
  items_in_stock << item
 elsif !in_stock.include?(item)
  items_not_in_stock << item
 end
end

# items_in_stock = ['flour', 'oil']
# items_not_in_stock = ['egg', 'salt']
```

```
<p>
 <%= items_in_stock.to_sentence %>
 <strong>
  <%= items_not_in_stock.to_sentence %>
 </strong>
</p>
```

As an outcome I get two sentences which is not ideal as it's supposed to be displayed as a single sentence with a few words highlighted (used strong just for eg.)

=> Flour and oil **Egg and salt**

#### I've also though of doing the following:

```rb
#checked_items = []
items.each do |item|
 if in_stock.include?(item)
  checked_items << item
 elsif !in_stock.include?(item)
  checked_items << "<span class='red'>#{item}</span>"
 end
end
```

But then I realize that it doesn't work, having as a result:

```
<p>
<%= checked_items.to_sentence %>
</p>

#=> Flour, oil, <span class='red'> egg </span> and <span class='red'> salt </span>
```

This is my first question on here, hope it's well explained.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```rb
items = ['flour', 'oil', 'egg', 'salt']
in_stock = ['flour', 'oil']

decorated_items = items.map do |item|
  if in_stock.include?(item)
    item
  else
    "<span class='red'>#{item}</span>" # you can also use: tag.span(item, class: 'red')
  end
end

# => ["flour", "oil", "<span class='red'>egg</span>", "<span class='red'>salt</span>"]
```

Here you will have an array, if you want to display them in the view layer (helpers or views), you'll need to safely join them:

```
safe_join(decorated_items) # which is better than decorated_items.join.html_safe
```

Comment: After some try and error, it worked flawlessly, thank you very much!  To conclude the 'sentence' like display, I've used ``` safe_join(decorated_items, ", ")``` to have a comma and a space in between words.